# Do mail interceptors get called when config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

That's really the whole question. I have some mail interceptors but when I set the delivery mode to test, they don't do their thing - is this to be expected?

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit of a nonstarter question but I'll leave the answer in case it helps anyone else.

It turns out the interceptor was actually running. The problem I was having is that because it was being executed via delayed_job and delayed_job does not reload the classes on each job (unsurprisingly), the fact that I'd changed the code had not yet filtered through to the jobs themselves.

On restarting the jobs worker, everything came back to normal